# task.json does contain build but it runs watch

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this task, but it does behave like watch : as soon as I type something it starts build compilation, why ?

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$tsc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is a `tsconfig` `watch` option.  Is there one in yours?

Comment: I give my tsconfig above : there is none

Comment: You don't actually show your `tsconfig.json` file...  What you do show is a task, from your `tasks.json`.